# Using lxml to generate XPath for a specific line

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

Is it possible to generate an XPath using a line number and python lxml library?

Background: we have references (not xpath, but parts of them) in the document and I would like to find all references to a specific element (in a specific line)

```
enter code here

<root>
  <element>
    <name>Element1</name>
    <contains>
      <element>
        <name>color</name>
        <value-ref>/Colors/red</value-ref>
      </element>
    </contains>
  </element>
  <element>
    <name>Colors</name>
    <contains>
      <element>
        <name>red</name>
        <value>0xFF0000</value>
      </element>
      <element>
        <name>blue</name>     <!-- the line I'd like to get an Xpath for -->
        <value>0x0000FF</value>
      </element>
    </contains>
  </element>
</root>
```

And out of the XPath I will make an expression like in value-ref (this can be done by regex)

Comment: Please provide a reproduceable example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now use

```
etree.iter()
```

to iterate over all elements and then compare the

```
element.sourceline
```

and compare it to the line I'm looking for. Now I have the element I'm looking for and can continue to generate the path as described above.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do something where you parse the doc, make a map of all the elements in the doc and their underlying line numbers (using the lxml `Element` object's `sourceline` attribute), and then work from there. But it's hard to be more specific without more explanation about the nature of what you're trying to do.

EDIT:

I still don't quite understand the problem, but in case it's useful, here's some Python code that uses lxml and shows both the location path (xpath) and line number for each element in your example doc:

```
import lxml.etree

doc = lxml.etree.parse('test.xml')
tree = lxml.etree.ElementTree(doc.getroot())
for e in tree.xpath('.//*'):
    print(tree.getpath(e), '-', e.sourceline)
```

Comment: Well I tried to keep the example as simple as possible. What i try to do is navigate through AUTOSAR xml files. They can be really large > 150000 lines and they contain these kind of links. I use vim and lxml to find a referenced element, and it work pretty neat. But sometimes I'd like to find all elements referencing the current element (identified by the current line/linennumber). Hope you this helps to get what I mean.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the vim + lxml combo (I am familiar with both on their own), so it's hard for me to picture the interaction here. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: The interaction is not the problem :) This is a part I already solved. But my problem is the transformation of a line into an xpath.